# Instances of simulating lambda calculus?

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus, turing-completeness

There are a ton of resources on the web devoted to proving some esoteric language is Turing complete by simulating arbitrary turing machines.  I have an esoteric language I want to prove is complete, but I'm pretty sure the easier way to do it would be to prove that you can express any untyped lambda calculus term in it; i.e.

Recursively, it can represent a name, x.
Given a lambda term E1 and E2 and a name v, it can represent lambda v.E1 as well as (E1)(E2).

Are there any existing examples of trying to prove a language is Turing complete through reduction to untyped (or any other Turing-complete) lambda calculus rather than through reduction to whether a Turing Machine halts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think the most famous example is the $\pi$-calculus, which Milner showed to be complete by such a reduction in [Functions as Processes](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/07/54/05/PDF/RR-1154.pdf).

Comment: [Here's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397513006415) another one, which encodes combinatory logic into Featherweight Java.